# What is the relationship between IRimTable and PersistenceStore?

Tags: blackberry, persistence

The BlackBerry Desktop API has the interface IRimTable which apparently maps an "application database" on a BlackBerry device to a virtual structure (i.e, IRimTable has IRimRecords, each of which has IRimField) that developer can browse the handheld device data when it is connected to a desktop computer.

Meanwhile, applications in the handheld device can store its data in PersistenceStore databases. The point where I'm stuck is the PersistenceStore API doesn't define any Table or Records or Fields.

Does anybody knows what is the relationship between these two classes? And how does the mapping work (if at all) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No correlation.  PersistenceStore deals with the storage on the device itself.  There are no field definitions because there is basically one field per row in the "table."  Your application has to manage the information if you want to store it using persistence store.